# Usar conexão bluetooth em duas activities

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estou criando um pequeno app com duas activities, a primeira é uma tela com apenas um botão 'conectar', depois de conectado ao módulo bluetooth ele mudaria pra segunda tela(Segunda activity) onde estariam os comando para mandar por bluetooth.

A duvida é: Como utilizar a conexão feita na primeira activity para enviar dados na segunda...

Pensei em passar o BluetoothSocket como um extra na intent, mas não foi possível porque não implementa serializable.

Comment: Você quer enviar o que **exatamente** da primeira para a segunda activity?

Comment: Então, aí esta o problema, nao sei ao certo que é necessario... mas ja tive a ideia de mandar o BluetoothSocket ou o InputStream....A minha intencao é isolar a conexao e o envio de dados

Comment: E minha última pergunta: qual o objetivo de repassar essas informações?

Comment: Nao queria que na outra tela que mando os comandos ficasse "poluida" com um botao de conectar...

Comment: Então você quer retirar esse botão? Não entendo qual o seu objetivo sobre passar parâmetros para uma segunda atividade. Pode explicar somente o objetivo sobre esse repasse? Ao que me parece você quer fazer algo simples através de muito trabalho.

Comment: Isso, queria fazer uma tela de entrada. Uma "capa" com o botao conectar. Caso a conexao se estabelecesse, ele entraria na segunda activity.

Comment: Acho que você deve isolar todos essa lógica que lida com Bluetooth para um Service, pois assim evitaria o acoplamento com uma determinada Activity.